# I got an invalid syntax error for this code

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a checker and got this error, pls i need help: here is the error im getting
File "python1.py", line 14
    print(f"Login Success e {email} & {password}")
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import requests
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool



lock = multiprocessing.Lock()


class output(object):
    def screen(self, email, password, case):
        if case==True:
            lock.acquire()
            print(f"Login Success e {email} & {password}")
            print(f"""
                e = {email}
                p = {password}
                """, file=open("live.txt", "a"))
            lock.release()
        elif case==False:
            lock.acquire()
            print(f"Login Failed e {email} & {password}")
            lock.release()
```

Comment: What version of Python 3 are you using? f-strings were introduced in 3.6

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a python version lower that **3.6** fro mwhere the fstrings where released. Your solution is either update or rely in the old trusty `str.format` method:

```
class output(object):
    def screen(self, email, password, case):
        if case==True:
            lock.acquire()
            print("Login Success e {email} & {password}".format(email=email, password=password))
            print("""
                e = {email}
                p = {password}
                """.format(email=email, password=password), file=open("live.txt", "a"))
            lock.release()
        elif case==False:
            lock.acquire()
            print("Login Failed e {email} & {password}".format(email=email, password=password))
            lock.release()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the heads up, I replaced the part of the code with yours and got this error: 

""".format(email=email, password=password), file=open("live.txt", "a"))
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax